# Math Tricks Reference

Tags: reference-request

Any suggestions of books with cool, possibly nonrigorous math tricks?

For example, Joel Spencer "Asymptopia" has some really cool results in integral estimation using asymptotic ideas (e.g. estimating Stirling's Formula).

Another example would be Sanjoy Mahajan "Street-Fighting Mathematics" where he presents lots of fun techniques for guessing calculations.

Finally, another book I can remember is Steele "The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class".

Comment: generatingfunctionology can give you quick ideas as to what a recurrence is going to look like.

Comment: For recreational mathematics, I'd recommend [Problems for Mathematicians, Young and Old](https://www.amazon.com/Problems-Mathematicians-DOLCIANI-MATHEMATICAL-EXPOSITIONS/dp/0883853205) by Halmos.  It should be a popular enough book that you can find it in libraries.  The solutions to problems all generally require a clever observation.